# can i add pipenv in a path ? and how to do it?

Tags: pipenv

[image]

I tried to install pipenv but I always get this problem and message that pipenv is not recognized , I uninstalled it and tried to install it again but I get get same issue

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: In the picture it says: "... which is not on PATH"  How to do that is explained here: [Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

Comment: @Luuk thx and sorry for uploading an image I'm new on these stuff:)